# Не отображается favicon в яндексе?

Tags: favicon

favicon на сайте [homeasking.com](https://homeasking.com) отлично отображается в браузере, в различных сервисах google (например, в веб-мастере), но в яндексе не отображается. В веб-мастере яндекса пишет, что "Файл favicon не найден". Заказывал уже 5 проверок, но результат все тот же. В чем проблема?

Comment: Как давно сайта находится в открытом доступе? Покажите ваш robot.txt

Comment: Месяца 3 как доступен для индексации. https://homeasking.com/robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

Согласно страничке `https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/search-results/favicon.html#check` запрос фавиконки должен возвращать код 200.

В вашем случае возвращается 301

https://webmaster.yandex.ru/tools/server-response/?url=homeasking.com%2Ffavicon.ico&user-agent=robot&if-modified-since=

Comment: Вы ввели без https, поэтому 301. С https выдает 200

Comment: https://webmaster.yandex.ru/tools/server-response/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhomeasking.com%2Ffavicon.ico&user-agent=robot&if-modified-since=

Comment: @Андрей, и правда, прошу прощения. Вроде бы все по требованиям. Наверно остается только обратиться в ТП Яндекса